Button Move when hide and visible Layout by setVisibility?
I have following layout code that inflate in windows manager and shows in floating windows.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topMenu">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mainButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/robot_foreground" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:text="Item1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/baseline_6_ft_apart_24"
            android:text="Item2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

I visible or hide mainMenu layout by setVisibility by clicking on mainButton.
if (mainMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mainMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);    }
 else {        mainMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    }

After hiding or showing the mainMenu layout, the location of the mainButton changes. have do fix the mainButton place when show or hide the mainMenu layout.
I searched through all the questions but couldn't find anything.
Help me please

Use ConstraintLayout instead of nesting multiple LinearLayouts.
